# Crystal Report Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new to C# and I am trying to view an already created crystal report using crystal report viewer. However I want users to be able to filter the result of the report based on some inputs from user end and I am not allowed to create these parameter fields in crystal report itself. Is it possible to programmatically pass the fields and values from c# ASP.net web form without having to declare these parameters in crystal report.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
        ParameterDiscreteValue dv = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramField.ReportName = "SiteDetailsFull.rpt";
        paramField.Name = "Site Name";
        dv.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(dv);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);
        aquaRptViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
```

Comment: How would the report know what to do with the parameters?

Comment: Thanks. I got a solution to it. Apparently I was using a wrong term. I needed to filter the result and I have used selectionformula to get that done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a parameter without declaring it in the report.

But you can use a formula to add your constraint and then pass it to report to get the data filter as you want.

Example:

```cs
formula = " FiledName =  Some filter date  ";
reportClass.RecordSelectionFormula = reportClass.RecordSelectionFormula + formula;
```